# Exchange Management Shell - Exchange 2010 - Exporting with DateRange to PST ignoring the filtering

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010, exchange-management-shell

I’ll elaborate on the title a bit.

I’m currently creating a script to export a mailbox on Exchange 2010 to a PST, only emails from a specific date range.

However, it seems to be ignoring the filter and exporting all 37gb to a PST.

I’m creating the script to prevent having to do it in the future. I will post the script below, as it is all relevant to the issue due to variables etc.

```
# / Sets to US Date Values \ #

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Threading")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Globalization")
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")

# / This Loads The Assemblies Required for Data Input for the future Parameters \ #

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles() | Out-Null

# / This Loads The Pop-up Data Input Windows For Creating the Parameters \ #

Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic

# / Parameter Creation Using Nice GUI Pop-Up Windows \ #

$User = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('What Is The Email Account?', 'Email Address', "Email@Email.com")
$StartDateData = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('What Is The Start Date (US Date Format)', 'Start Date', "12/25/1900")
$EndDateData = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('What Is The End Date (US Date Format)', 'End Date', "12/25/1900")
$Path = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Specify Where You Want The PST to Be Saved (Full UNC Path WITH Trailing Slash)', 'Path', "C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\")

# / Export Mailbox \ #
cls
Write-Host ''
Write-Host ''
Write-Host ''
Write-Host ''
Write-Host ''
Write-Host ''
Write-Host 'Is this Data Correct?'
Write-Host ''
Write-Host ''
Write-Host $User 
Write-host $StartDateData
Write-host $EndDateData
write-host $Path
Write-Host ''
Write-Host ''
Write-Host ''
Write-Host "Do You Want To Continue? (Y/N)"
$response = Read-Host
if ( $response -ne "Y" ) { 
exit
}

cls

# / Sets The Path Parameter \ #
$PSTPath = $Path + $User + ".pst"

# / Sets The Date Parameter \ #

$StartDate = "'" + $StartDateData + "'"
$EndDate = "'" + $EndDateData + "'"

# Use This if the Below Doesn't Work - Export-Mailbox -Identity $User -StartDate $StartDate -EndDate $EndDate -PstFolderPath $PSTPath

# gt = Greater-Than
# ge = Greater-Than-Or-Equal-To
# lt = Less-Than
# le = Less-Than-Or-Equal-To

$Request = New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $User -ContentFilter {(Received -ge $StartDate) -and (Received -le $EndDate)} -FilePath $PSTPath

$Status = ( Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics -Identity $Request ).Status.ToString().Trim()

while( $Status -ne 'Completed' ){
    Start-Sleep 10

    $Status = ( Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics -Identity $Request ).Status.ToString().Trim()

    Write-Verbose "Current Export Status: $Status" -Verbose
    }a

Write-Verbose "$Mailbox exported" -Verbose
```

Apologies about the bulk, I can’t personally see an error.

Comment: I don't know what type or format `New-MailboxExportRequest` or `Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics` expect `$StartDate/$EndDate` to be. Actually they are just strings without any validation.

Comment: @LotPings don’t understand what you mean mate, elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up fixing this myself after A LOT of playing around.

Had to throw the filter into it's own parameter, like so

```
$filter = "(Received -ge" + " " + $StartDate + ") -and (Received -le" + " " + $EndDate + ")"
```

then pipe it into the command

```
$Request = New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter $filter -Mailbox $User -Name $ReqName -FilePath $PSTPath
```

This has allowed it to progress